# Finding dependencies of package manager is super slow

Tags: react-native, watchman, packager

Running my react-native app on the device via

```
react-native run-ios
```

or

```
react-native run-android
```

starts the package manager but takes super long until the app is loaded because the dependencies are not loaded. In total it takes 297646ms to load all the dependencies which is probably not normal.
I already restarted my computer and the package manager but it takes every time that long.

The output of my package manager terminal is:

[

```
12:28:56 PM] <START> find dependencies  
[12:30:42 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true  
[12:31:57 PM] <END>   Crawling File System (342321ms)  
[12:31:57 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript  
[12:32:00 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (2127ms)  
[12:32:00 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets  
[12:32:01 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (1268ms)  
[12:32:01 PM] <START> Building Haste Map  
[12:32:01 PM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map  
[12:32:02 PM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (351ms)  
[12:32:02 PM] <END>   Building Haste Map (1155ms)  
[12:32:02 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (346928ms)  
transformed 625/625 (100%)  
[12:33:53 PM] <END>   find dependencies (297646ms)
```

Comment: Is your code on a network share or something similar? It looks like the file system is the bottleneck.

Comment: No it's on all on my macbooks SSD. No network drives or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's always slow to start, but as the packager runs, it's not an issue.